# ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT with Storage Access Framework returns duplicate results

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I'm trying to select images using Storage Access Framework and upload them to my server.
The problem I'm encountering is that after selecting files I get result which contains duplicates.
I have 279 photos in the folder.
`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` returns 279 results, but some of them are duplicates, so sometimes I get 275 unique results, sometimes 268, etc. 
The duplicates appear at random, so they are not specific files.

Here is the code:

```
int PICKER_CODE = 123;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);

            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Select images"), PICKER_CODE);
            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing was chosen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if (requestCode == PICKER_CODE) {

        ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();

        if (clipData != null) {

            Set<Uri> uniqueUris = new HashSet<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                Uri photoUri = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();

                uniqueUris.add(photoUri);

                Log.i("IMAGE PICKER", "photo: " + photoUri);
            }

            String stats =
                    "all: " + clipData.getItemCount()
                            + ", unique: " + uniqueUris.size();

            Log.i("IMAGE PICKER", "stats: " + stats);

            Toast.makeText(this, stats, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output_text);
            textView.setText(stats);
        }
    }
```

}

The full code of the activity is here: https://github.com/Leonti/android-saf-duplicates/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/leonti/googledriveduplicatesdebugging/MainActivity.java

Here is the sample Android app where you can reproduce the issue:
https://github.com/Leonti/android-saf-duplicates
Just install it on the phone, select some images (the more the better) and it will tell you the total count and the number of unique entries.

It doesn't matter if I select photos from Google Drive or from Photos, most of the times I get duplicate results.

Can't figure out what is going wrong.
I executed the same code on Android emulator (used another account and shared this Google Drive folder) and it's working as expected - all results are unique.

I'm running Android 7.0 on Nexus 5X

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where do you see duplicates? In Clipdata or in one of the array lists that you make?

Comment: It makes no sense to post such a big list. Do we have to inspect that? How would we have to do that?

Comment: I see duplicates in both Clipdata and in an array that I'm making since I'm making an array from Clipdata

@greenapps I included the list just for a reference, no one has to inspect that. The important part is that it has duplicates. But, if someone thinks that the actual results are relevant, they can use online tools like: http://www.somacon.com/p568.php to see the duplicates and maybe see a pattern.

Comment: Please post the duplicates as text here. Of course its interesting. Post also some non duplicates. If you see a pattern then please tell.

Comment: Is your result a result of a 'select all' by the user or touching individual files?

Comment: If the user only selects the duplicates, then what do you get?

Comment: Or if the user selects only the ones that were not included before.

Comment: The result is of 'Select All' action
I don't know what happens if user select the duplicates because there is only 1 duplicate in the folder on Google Drive, the rest of the files are unique.

Comment: Also the same code on emulator with the same Google Drive folder works just fine.

Comment: Did you try using the opener intent to pick a file? See same code of [Google Drive Android API Demos](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos)

Comment: I would like to use SAF instead of specific Google Drive API, users should be able to select images from anywhere they want

Comment: I updated the question as on my phone I get duplicates even if I'm not selecting from Google Drive.
I also provided a sample app to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's a bug in Android Nougat.
I was able to reproduce it on my phone (Nexus 5X) and on emulator (Google Apis 24)
Maybe it's somehow connected to "virtual files" introduced in Nougat SAF:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#virtual_files

It works as expected on Android 6.0 emulator

Created a bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=224592

Comment: The bug is fixed in Android 7.1 beta :)